# Bootstrap 4 tooltip arrow shadow styling

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-tooltip

This is the tooltip's arrow without shadow:

[image]

I'm trying to shadow it but since the arrow is made out of borders I've been unable to render a proper result. Getting the following:

[image]

**Any ideas how to integrate the arrow part's shadow to the rest of the tooltip?** (Snippet below)

Checked the [following](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50727753/bootstrap-tooltip-arrow-style) and some others but couldn't find a shadow specific scenario.

Thank you.

```js
$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip('show');
```

```css
html body {
  background: #eee;
}

button.btn {
  margin-top: 100px;
}

.tooltip-inner {
  background-color: white !important;
  color: gray !important;
  border-radius: 0 !important;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px 0px rgba(161, 161, 161, 1);
}

.bs-tooltip-right .arrow::before {
  border-right-color: white !important;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px 0px rgba(161, 161, 161, 1);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Something">
  Some tooltip
</button>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can achieve this with a little css magic and applying the styling to the `::after` pseudo element.  Added the shadow there and dropped the z-index to -1 to sit behind and give the desired effect.

```js
$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip('show');
```

```css
html body {
  background: #eee;
  margin: 30px;
}

.tooltip-inner {
  background-color: white !important;
  color: gray !important;
  border-radius: 0 !important;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px 0px rgba(161, 161, 161, 1);
}

.bs-tooltip-right .arrow::before {
  border-right-color: white !important;
}

.bs-tooltip-right .arrow::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
  border: 5px solid #fff;
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px 0px rgba(161, 161, 161, 1);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Something">
  Some tooltip
</button>
```

Comment: bhmahlet, would you mind providing me examples for top, left and bottom placements? I've tried tweaking your right placement example for the others but no luck. Here's an updated fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/Syden/6h9p5nju/1/ in case you wish to help. If you do, I will update the question to include all placements. Thank you.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/g0v6547n/ This fiddle illustrates all 4 types changed.  I actually modified the scss file for tooltip in the bootstrap source to generate this.  Let me know if you want the scss source